# What is data type for Python Keras deep learning package?

Tags: python, theano, keras

I didn't find anything about data type that we need to work with `Python Keras deep learning package` with [this](http://keras.io/) link. I checked array and list but returned error. Any clue?

Comment: i think it explained in http://keras.io/layers/core/  ! for example Dense is a data type used and it explained it

Comment: What is this data type? I'm not familiar with it. More information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keras uses `numpy` arrays containing the `theano.config.floatX` floating point type. This can be configured in your [`.theanorc`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html#envvar-THEANORC) file.

Typically, it will be `float64` for CPU computations and `float32` for GPU computations, although you can also set it to `float32` when working on the CPU if you prefer.

You can create a zero-filled array of the proper type by the command

```
X = numpy.zeros((4,3), dtype=theano.config.floatX)
```

Comment: @user2991243: An example for what?

Comment: Create a sample data-set for this package. A simple array to insert this package functions.

Comment: @user2991243: I have added an example to create a 4x3 array.

Comment: @cfh when adding training data do I include the output part/column of the training data in this array?