# Keras machine learning sum of inputs via linear network

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, linear-regression

I am currently doing a project with Keras in which I try to determine a value associated with a set of eigenvalues. But my network keeps giving me impossibly high losses and it doesn't improve (I don't expect good results but I expect better than a mean absolute error several orders of magnitude larger than my target value). So I tried to do a stepback and just do a linear network which calculates the sum of the eigenvalues. This should be easy since the weights of the network should easily go to just ones.

I have two arrays consisting of the input and target value (that I converted into [the right shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34448582/how-to-input-data-into-keras-specifically-what-is-the-x-train-and-y-train-if-i) from a pandas DataFrame):

```
X = []
y = []
for i in data.index:
    X.append(np.array(data['eigenvalues'][i]))
    #y.append(data['potentialEnergy'][i])
    y.append(sum(data['eigenvalues'][i]))

X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)

print(X[0])
print(y[0])
print(X[15000])
print(y[15000])
print(np.shape(X))
print(np.shape(y))
```

```
[ -1406.74309308   -898.24456965   -793.63886376  13167.21786484
 -44377.13445138 -23093.63982765 -18195.74157748 157644.73205433]
82046.80753617459
[  -799.79720655   -427.93821681     97.62326501   1492.26952451
 -20504.5373352   -9193.39857798   4821.74098972  25848.52186994]
1334.4843126587984
(31521, 8)
(31521,)
```

So that seems good. I than build and train a network:

```
learningRate = 1*10**-3
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=8, use_bias=False))
model.add(Activation("linear"))
opt = adam(lr=learningRate)
model.compile(loss='MAE', optimizer=opt)

fitDetails = model.fit(X, y, epochs=30, verbose=1)

for i in range(len(model.layers)):
    print('Layer ' + str(i) + ': ', model.layers[i].get_weights())
```

```
Epoch 1/30
31521/31521 [==============================] - 2s 48us/step - loss: 3266171041.9287
Epoch 2/30
31521/31521 [==============================] - 2s 49us/step - loss: 7649753416.7438
...
Epoch 29/30
31521/31521 [==============================] - 1s 44us/step - loss: 9600477128.1926
Epoch 30/30
31521/31521 [==============================] - 1s 44us/step - loss: 4003147634.3867

Layer 0:  [array([[ 0.6709176 ],
       [-3.3879364 ],
       [-1.4577906 ],
       [-0.11517545],
       [ 0.4304375 ],
       [-0.24380146],
       [ 0.8325586 ],
       [ 0.1383722 ]], dtype=float32)]
Layer 1:  []
```

Which is very weird since the weights should just go to 1. I then try to manualy set the weights to 1:

```
model.layers[0].set_weights([np.array([[1] for i in range(8)])])
for i in range(len(model.layers)):
    print('Layer ' + str(i) + ': ', model.layers[i].get_weights())

model.evaluate(X, y)
```

```
Layer 0:  [array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.]], dtype=float32)]
Layer 1:  []
31521/31521 [==============================] - 1s 23us/step

20.5936894862014
```

Which is even stranger.

So does anybody know what is going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest you make the example fully reproducible by forgetting the eigenvalues of the data we don't have, and using dummy artificial data instead (in any case, trying to build a model that sums up its inputs doesn't have anything in particular to do with eigenvalues). BTW, your network is actually a simple linear regression.